# Validating FormData objects with Joi

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

Just wondering if there's a way to pass a FormData object to Joi, or whether I have to convert it to an object myself?

I couldn't see anything in the docs, but thought I'd ask as it seems strange the option isn't there

`const formData = new FormData(e.target);`

// data is an object of inputNames/values

```
validate = (data, schema) => {
    const options = {
        abortEarly: false
    };
    const result = Joi.validate(data, schema, options);
};
```

Obviously I could do somthing like this:

```
for(let pair of formData.entries()) {
  formObject[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
```

but it was just a QoL thing I thought I might have missed

Comment: Is `Object.fromEntries(myFormData.entries())` that onerous? But the point of joi is to be a generic object validator with no ties to web APIs.

Comment: No, not at all. But you might not have seen my edit, I was looping over the form object - whereas I should've been using `Object.fromEntries()`, so thanks :)

Comment: Looping over the entries doesn't seem that bad either :shrug: